# Scraping a widget

Tags: python, selenium

I am scraping data and it was scraping and printing what was appearing on the first page, however there was tons more data below.  So, next I added code to scroll down to the bottom of the page so everything could be scraped.  The problem now is that it scrolls to the bottom but then it just waits and never prints.  Anyone know how to get this to print and eventually I'd the results to go to an excel file if anyone knows how to that too.   Thanks so much

```
 from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://www.tradingview.com/screener'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 2

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

# will give a list of all tickers
tickers = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.tv-screener__symbol') 

# will give a list of all company names
company_names = driver.find_elements_by_css('span.tv-screener__description') 

# will give a list of all close values
close_values = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class = 'tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--numeric']/span") 

# will give a list of all percentage changes
percentage_changes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[3]') 

# will give a list of all value changes
value_changes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[4]')

# will give a list of all ranks
ranks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[5]/span')

# will give a list of all volumes
volumes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[6]')

# will give a list of all market caps
market_caps = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[7]')

# will give a list of all PEs
pes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[8]')

# will give a list of all EPSs
epss = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[9]')

# will give a list of all EMPs
emps = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[10]')

# will give a list of all sectors
sectors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[11]')

for index in range(len(tickers)):
   print("Row " + index + " " + tickers[index].text + " " + company_names[index].text + " ")
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167327/scraping-the-full-content-from-a-lazy-loading-webpage. You can also google lazy loader for other code samples.

Comment: I wasn't able to adapt this to my code or get the new code to work.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to locate a wrong element. This:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_id('js-screener-container')
```

should be replaced with:

```
# will give a list of all tickers
tickers = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.tv-screener__symbol') 

# will give a list of all company names
company_names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.tv-screener__description') 

# will give a list of all close values
close_values = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class = 'tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--numeric']/span") 

# will give a list of all percentage changes
percentage_changes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[3]') 

# will give a list of all value changes
value_changes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[4]')

# will give a list of all ranks
ranks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[5]/span')

# will give a list of all volumes
volumes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[6]')

# will give a list of all market caps
market_caps = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[7]')

# will give a list of all PEs
pes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[8]')

# will give a list of all EPSs
epss = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[9]')

# will give a list of all EMPs
emps = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[10]')

# will give a list of all sectors
sectors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[11]')
```

So now you have all data stored in lists. If you want to build a rows of data, you can use something like this:

```
for index in range(len(tickers)):
   print("Row " + tickers[index].text + " " + company_names[index].text + " " + ....)
```

Output will be something like this:

```
Row AAPL APPLE INC. 188.84 -1.03% -1.96 Neutral 61.308M 931.386B 17.40 10.98 123K Technology 
Row AMZN AMAZON.COM INC 1715.97 -0.46% -7.89 Buy 4.778M 835.516B 270.53 6.54 566K Consumer Cyclicals
...
```

**PS:**

I think

```
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5
```

is too small ammount of time, since sometimes loading new content by scrolling on the page bottom may be longer as `0.5 seconds`. I would increase this value to make sure that all content will be loaded.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code.  I changed to your code in the original post but nothing prints?  Any idea if I did something wrong?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake in the for loop. `String` and `int` cannot be concatenated like this. So the code is edited. If it won't work try to print one element `print(tickers[0].text)`

Comment: Amazing work!!  The only one I'm getting an error on is company_names = driver.find_elements_by_css('span.tv-screener__description')   It's also not working unless I remove the scrolling code so that's a problem too.  Thanks

Comment: There was a typo there. I have uodated code, just use `company_names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.tv-screener__description')`. I'm happy to hear, that your problem is solved. If you are satisfied with my help, please mark my answer by clicking on the green check button below downvote button. Have a nice day!

Comment: Is it possible to get column headings?